# Database does not accept decimal values in live

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, dapper

I am using the following bit of code to insert some data into a database:

```
internal int InsertSample(Sample sample)
{
    using (var db = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var query = Constants.InsertNewSample;
        return db.Execute(query, sample);
    }
}
```

And it works fine when I run it locally through Visual Studio.

However, when I publish the site and try inserting, I get an error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

**Stack trace**

```
[OleDbException (0x80040e07): Data type mismatch in criteria expression.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1138392
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +208
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +162
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +107
   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) +93
   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) +758
   MVCQCPage.Helpers.Access.InsertSample(Sample sample) +208
```

But this only happens if the value of `Sample.MassOff` is in decimal format (e.g. `1.6`).

If this value is passed as an integer (e.g. `5`), it works without any issue when debugging and after publishing.

**How is this possible????**

The data type in the database is `numeric`, and the data type of `Sample.MassOff` is `string`.

Let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: What kind of library extends the classic OleDbException with an Execute method? Are you using Dapper?

Comment: Does Access even **have** a `numeric` data type?

Comment: @Steve Apologies steve, yes it is dapper. @stuartd I think it may be called `number`

Comment: Do you have some type of mapping you can configure for Dapper for this model? Maybe that mapping is not correct or needs to be extended so the correct type is used. Can you capture the full query and the parameter values/types that are being sent from Dapper? Or does dapper do string concatenation on the query (*I hope not*).

Comment: If your database field is numeric why do you have a model with a string type for that field? Can you simply change it to be a (double/float/decimal)?

Comment: [SE - using decimal type #261](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/261) <= has a demonstration of how to use parameters. What @Steve said as well, I assumed you had the correct types and not string, do not use string use the native type(s) and if you only have strings then convert them to the native type as early in the stack as possible to the correct type.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the tips - that makes a lot of sense and I will have to test thisi in a bit when I get home. I still don't understand why this would work when debugging but not when published to the server (could somehow be a combination of data types and region settings??)

Comment: I am not sure. If you wanted to pursue that your best bet would be to capture what is actually sent to the access store and then replay that on the server to see if it is accepted there or not. It might be localization as well, that on the server the thread culture is different then the culture on your local machine but on the server that culture does not match the culture of the server so maybe . and , are switched (10.5 becomes 10,5 in c# and is not accepted on the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following:

- Changing the data type of `MassOff` to `double`
- Adding the line `<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />` to `web.config`

Answer (score 2):

Culture of the system must be an issue here. Make sure Culture of your development system and deployment system is same.

If you cannot control/change Culture of deployment system, you can set Culture of your application as below:

## Web Application (Your case)

Set `globalization` attribute in `web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />/*Whatever your default culture you want to use irrespective of system*/
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

## Windows Application (May be helpful for others)

If you are using DotNet Framework 4.5, following will do:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");//Whatever your default culture you want to use irrespective of system
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

If you are using DotNet Framework 4 or earlier, following is the trick:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");//Whatever your default culture you want to use irrespective of system
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

Type type = typeof(CultureInfo);
type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultCulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    cultureInfo,
                    new object[] { cultureInfo });

type.InvokeMember("s_userDefaultUICulture",
                    BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
                    null,
                    cultureInfo,
                    new object[] { cultureInfo });
```

Call above code at the start of your application.

Comment: As seen in my answer I believe this was a combiniation of this and my use of the incorrect data type

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I passed decimal values through. The problem was with parsing the separator dot / comma. The whole thing was a mess... I just ended up encrypting it into a string representation back and forth :)

Comment: Did you also only experience this when it was sitting on the server? I tried calling `Replace(',', '.');` on `MassOff` but got the same error

Comment: It didn't go through the dev-test so no. But some guru said that it had to do something with culture invariant features. But i don't dare say it's the same situation as yours.